# Intermittent errors when running standard PowerShell commands alongside Runspaces in a WPF application

Tags: powershell, runspace

I'm currently working on a PowerShell tool using WPF that runs multiple Runspaces. I cannot share the full code, but I can describe the main steps of my implementation:

1. Create a WPF `$window` element, but don't display it yet.
2. Create a new PowerShell object and bind it to a RunspacePool.
3. Pass a script block to the Runspace, along with the `$window` element as a parameter. This allows me to close the window from the Runspace using `$window.Dispatcher([...])`.
4. In my main thread, display the window with `ShowDialog()`. This keeps the window responsive and the code "waits" until the window is closed from the Runspace.
5. In my main thread, run standard PowerShell commands (e.g., `Write-Warning 'foo'`).

At step 5, it's possible that the Runspace is still running (`$handle.isCompleted() -eq $false`).

I'm encountering intermittent errors where standard PowerShell commands cannot be found. These errors happen randomly and are not consistently reproducible.

Is it possible that a running Runspace could block these commands, causing the errors? If not, what could be the cause of these errors, and how can I resolve them?

The error message is for example:

```
The term 'write-host' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
```

The command can be replaced with any command preinstalled by PowerShell. Sometimes the error occurs only when the command is executed the second time.

Comment: Please add an error example [to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76102556/edit). Btw if the errors are intermittent, it unlikely that there being blocked by a thread, it is more likely that they are related to the UI usage and certain constrains in your script.

Comment: I did some more browsing on the internet and came across the following post:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/edc4ae2d-b804-4361-94de-7482533a8084

This seems to be exactly my problem. However, I have PowerShell version 5.1 and the problem still occurs. Is there possibly a term for this problem under which I can also find something on the Internet?